# Does Data have Bluetooth or similar radio?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

Every time I see Data interacting with a computer or network he is using a terminal or communicator just like everyone else.  Surely a bluetooth or communicator device could easily be incorporated into his body.

Does he have integrated wireless and just chooses not to use it to appear more human, or is there some other canon reason for not being wireless?

Data at terminal wearing a communicator 
[image]

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Zeerust

Comment: I think Data is designed to be as human as possible. Hence, he is required to interact with computers as a human does.

Comment: Lore communicates with Data's emotion chip wirelessly in TNG: Descent Parts 1&2

Comment: What I want to know is... can he pick up FM?

Comment: “Now, what I’m saying is, no matter how hard I twiddle it, I can’t seem to pick up Jazz FM.”